# Multiple series disable and enable all series in PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, charts, series

I have a line chart with multiple series and I want to create a button to disable and enable all series at the same time.

**Chart with multiple series**
[image]

If you click on a serie on the legend, it will be disabled, but I need a button to disable all series at the same time.

I use the same example as here: [Example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/line.xhtml)

Is it possible to implement that with Primefaces?

Comment: Use some Chart API and Integrate it with your application

Comment: I try simulating a click   `$(".jqplot-table-legend").trigger("click");` but don’t work!